# Setting up a sub domain on AWS using only an ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip

I'm trying out AWS's free Tier and have set up a website using AMP that I can access with my public ip (`Eg 12.121.12.222`).

I don't plan on registering a domain name. Is it possible to setup something like `sub.12.121.12.222` on AWS without having a domain name?

Comment: IP address is not a domain. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Achieve `site-a.12.121.12.222 `, `site-b.12.121.12.222 `, `site-c.12.121.12.222 ` etc.

Comment: Its not possible. IP address is not DNS name.